# Does Spring Integration have a proxy support for FTP?

Tags: java, spring, ftp, kotlin, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration to code FTP-Client for remote files synchronization. So how can I fetch files from remote FTP-Server through proxy? Or does `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` (or `CachingSessionFactory`) deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

FTPHTTPClient provides you support to inject in the PROXY HOST and PROXY PORT. This link might give some light on how to pass these information to FTPHTTPClient 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java

You need a way to create an instance of FTPHTTPClient while calling createClientInstance() method.

Comment: We have an opened JIRA like this https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2505. Feel free to provide your feedback there and we may reconsider plans for it and will implement some improvement this or other way.